# Is there a way to avoid to convert number types in Scala? Should I use Numeric, Integral?

Tags: scala, types, casting

I would like to not to mind about type of numbers.
All numbers could be treated as Double,
but I would like to know the better scalaish way to use numbers just as numbers.

**This is just one example**, suppose I have the following:

```
val n = 5
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5) grouped (n / 2d).ceil.toInt
```

Is there a way to do just (**exactly**):

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5) grouped (n / 2).ceil
```

with no compilation error due to the mismatched type of 'grouped' parameter?

EDIT

The `n / 2` in `grouped (n / 2).ceil` part could be, in another example, the non integer result of a function `f`:

```
grouped f.ceil
```

It still needs type **conversion**, or in all situations there is a trick or design pattern to avoid it?

Comment: For the record, things like `toInt` or `toFloat` are _not_ casts, they're conversions. In conversions a method is called to execute some code to transform a value that is usually a new value. In contrast, casting in Scala is notated with `asInstanceOf`. In casting an existing value is simply asserted to have a different type (either narrower or, sometimes, wider). The result is the original value with a altered static type.

Comment: Tnx, now I understand people negativating my question; I corrected it.   "Real type conversion" was what I meant. Trying to use a least bad English, I ended up using the wrong word.

Comment: Note that the grouped call is IMHO a bit ugly. It does not look like a method call. 'd prefer to add a dot before `grouped` method name.

Comment: With a dot would it be more idiomatic?

Comment: @davips In infix style (without dot), you use a space between method name and parenthesis.

Comment: @Daniel tnx, I hope it is now more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out the numeric library [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire), I believe it has what you are looking for, namely, the ability to treat numbers as numbers whether they are int/double/float/etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5) grouped((n + 1) / 2)
```

Comment: That solves the example, but not the question. But tnx anyway for being friendly trying to answer.

Comment: @davips This can be used for any division. I think is answers your question, doesn't it? If not, specify the question, please.

Comment: @v6ak I don't know if I can put it in clear terms, it is kind of style of programming. To write that line, Daniel had to think about "integer division" and things like that. Or hadn't he?

Comment: @davips But the expression (n+1)/2 is about integer division. When you compute `n/2` in Scala, you get integer result rounded towards zero. If you want to round `n/k` towards infinity, you can compute `(n+k-1)/k` and round it towards infinity. (If `n%k == 0`, you get a result that equal to `n/k`. If `n%k > 0`, you get `n/k + 1`.) I don't think there is a better way in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a way to do it. You can define an implicit conversion like this:

```
implicit def double2Int(d: Double): Int = d.toInt
```

Once that's in scope, it will convert any `Double` automatically to `Int`. However, doing so is not recommended, as you lose type safety.

Comment: with scala 2.10 you can now use implicit classes to make that a bit more readable

Comment: @DanielCSobral: Why does this lose type safety? Implicit conversions are only applied when the expression as explicitly typed does not type-check and when the available implicit conversions are not ambiguous.

Comment: @RandallSchulz If you have a `Double` where you should have an `Int`, it is quite possible that you don't have what you thought you had. A compiler error will tell you so, but an implicit conversion will let the program run, and possibly introduce a bug that is difficult to track. I realize that Scala _allows_ you to do so, and I'm not saying you should never do it. All I'm saying is that you should do so with care.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: While it's true that a narrowing weak conformance conversion (e.g., floating to integer) is, by definition, information-losing, it that does not mean it's not type-safe.